# Is there any restriction to having a .class or .java file as resources in an Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently experiencing problems as I'm trying to puta `.class` file as a resource of my Java project under Eclipse. I'm also sure to have had problems in the past when trying to put a `.java` file as a resource file. Although Eclipse doesn't yell at all, trying to manipulate the resource at runtime gives me trouble. I can only hypothesize it has something to do with treating them in a special way for they are language specific extensions.

Is there any way to circumvent this problem, other than using either a different extension or none at all?

I'm currently trying to have a `.class` file as resource so I can copy it at runtime to a user-specified folder. When defining the resource as `MyResource.class` I'll have trouble opening, but as soon as I change it to `MyResource` everything works perfectly and as expected.

---

After some inspection I came to the conclusion that Eclipse isn't putting the `.class` file on correspondent folder in the ouput directory (it's simply ignoring it). Any idea on how to override this behavior?

Comment: It's stated in the last paragraph

Comment: ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("MyResource.class") returns null

Comment: Did you try `getResourceAsStream` instead of `getSystemResource...`?

Comment: @DaveNewton: I've tried this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MyResource.class") as well but didn't seem to work.

Comment: @devouredelysium Define "doesn't seem to work". Are you using a fully-qualified name, or is it really at the root? Also, it looks like if it's at the root classloader level it just defers to systemResource anyway. Did you try as "/MyResource.class"? You could also resort to grabbing it from the file system and/or jar file [as per here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/ResponsibleforloadingclassfilesfromtheCLASSPATHInspiredbysuntoolsClassPath.htm), but I'm still not sure if that would be necessary.

Comment: I'm using a qualified name ("abc/MyResource.class")

Comment: Are you sure? Eclipse normally puts class files into its build directory, at least mine does. And the class will be on the classpath, obviously.

Comment: Eclipse *compiles .java files* and puts the result as a .class file on the output directory. That's not the same as copying .class files it finds in its src/resource directory and putting them on the bin dir!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds really as expected, at least to me. Java is trying to load or use classes that have the ending in (already compiled):

> .class

What did you expect? It's like the same when having a jar in your classpath that you try to use, inside the jar you will have a bunch of .class files that you will refer to. Or did I not understand anything?

Comment: "This sounds really as expected, at least to me. Java is trying to load or use classes that have the ending in (already compiled):" That doesn't explain why I can't, nonetheless, access MyResource.class.

Comment: @devouredelysium this is normal. What if for example you try to run a class from command line? You do it : *java Foo*, you do not specify the .class extension, this is the way Java works - you do not specify the extension at all, it is auto-assumed.

Comment: One thing is when one tries to refer to a class, other thing when one tries to refer to a file (as in the current case). Are you suggesting that calling getResourceAsStream("MyContract") will work? because I've tried it and it doesn't.

Comment: Putting it more bluntly: I don't care whether the current behavior makes sense or not, I'm just looking for a way to having a .class file as resource and being able to use it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, right-click on your project and pick `Properties > Java Build Path` and then the `Libraries` tab.  Use `Add Class Folder` to create a folder at the same level as the `src` folder.

Then you can place your `.class` files (in their appropriate package folders) under the Class Folder, and they'll be copied into bin/ as part of the build process.